# Change the .ssh key used by git on windows

Tags: git, ssh

I am trying to push a code to a remote repository with which one of my two accounts on github are authorized. Corresponding to the two accounts, I have two ssh keys in my .ssh folder: id_rsa and id_rsa_rahulserver

I want to use the second key instead of the first, but whenever I do a git push, I get this messageછ

```
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/rahul/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

So always its taking up the first key instead of second(thereby giving the not authorized error). What should I do to make it accept second key instead of first for git push?

Answer (score 0):

create a file  '`config`' in  `.ssh/`  if you don't have it already and add the following

```
Host github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_rahulserver
```

Comment: It does not work in my case. It keeps asking the password for the wrong key.